# Count adjacent numbers in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to go through the elements of a 2D array and count the number of 1s adjacent to the user selected square. I am having trouble sorting out the 1s in the direct 9 squares touching the  selected square. The code below shows the `reveal(int row, int col)` command. Also, below shows an example of a 2D array that could be used.

```
/** 
 * The reveal command. Reveals the user inputted square and displays the number of
 * the number of mines adjacent to the square.
 */
pubic void reveal(int row, int col) {
   int minesTouching = 0;
   for (int x = 0; x < this.rows; x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y < this.cols; y++) {
           if (this.grid[x][y] == 1) {
              minesTouching++;
           } // if
       } // for
   } // for
   this.userGrid[row][col] = String.valueOf(minesTouching);
} // reveal
```

This is the method for the reveal command

```
int[][] grid = {1 0 0 0},
               {0 1 0 0},
               {0 0 1 0},
               {0 0 0 1};
```

This is the mineField in int form where 1s are mines and 0s are non-mines. I use this grid in `reveal()` to check the postition of the mines in relation to the user selected square. However when printing to the screen I use `userGrid[][]` which is a String array which can hold some other commands I have as well as the number of adjacent mines. The output should look like this:[image: This is the output of the program which shows that according to the grid array there are two adjacent mines.].

I would like to go through all elements in the array but only count the 1s in the direct 9 of the selected square. Any help would be appreciated and if you need more detail please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I feel this Question need more clarity, in question you are saying adjacent to the selected square but in method you are going through all the elements of the from beginning to the square, For Example 
If I say adjacent of (1,2) = (0,1), (0,2),(0,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)
but according to your method you are going through all like (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1)

Answer (score 0):

not the most ellegant, but the most simple solution i guess:

```
      public void review(int row, int col){
          int minesTouching;
          for(int i=row-1;i<=row+1;i++){
           for(int j=col-1;j<=col+1;j++){
            if(grid[i][j]==1){
             minesTouching++
            }
           }      
          }
        }
```

(I am assuming that the square [row][col] has already before been checked for not containing a mine )
I hope this answered your qouestion

Comment: You have to check that row - 1 is not less than zero and row + 1 is not greater than the row length - 1.  You have to perform the same check for the column.